# insert data into multiple columns in a database using mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have an html form in my site which i created so that users who access my site will be able to signup, the form has the following input; username, gender, email and password.

I will like to know how to use mysqli prepared statements (in order to protect my site from sql injections) in inserting the form data into multiple columns in my database with the users ip address.

Below is a code which i wrote (with validations) from tutorials i learnt from and from answers i read here.

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    // connect to db
    include 'db.php';

    // variables
    $msg = $error = $error0 = $error1 = $error2 = ""; 

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        // username validation
        if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
            $error= '<font color="#dc3545">Your username is required</font>';
        } elseif (strlen(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/m', '', $_POST["username"])) < 3) {
            $error= '<font color="#dc3545">Your username must have atleast 3 letters</font>';
        } elseif (strlen(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/m', '', $_POST["username"])) > 15) {
            $error= '<font color="#dc3545">Your username is too long</font>';
        } elseif (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+$/ ", $_POST["username"])) {
            $error = '<font color="#dc3545">Your username must be in letters with either a number(0-9), underscore(_) or dot(.)</font>';
        } else {
            // prepare select statement
            $check_uname = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $check_uname)) {

                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

                // Set parameters
                $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

                    /* store result */
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                        $error = '<font color="#dc3545"><b>'.$_POST["username"].'</b> is already in use</font>'; 
                    } else{
                        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);  
                    }
                } else{
                    $error = '<font color="#dc3545">Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later</font>';
                }
            }
            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        // gender validation
        if (empty($_POST['gender'])) {
            $error0 = '<font color="#dc3545">Your gender is required</font>';
        } else {
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        }

        // email validation
        if (empty(trim($_POST["email"]))) {
            $error1 = '<font color="red">Your email address is required</font>';
        } elseif (!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error1 = '<font color="red">Your email address is invalid</font>';
        } else {
            // prepare select statement
            $check_email = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $check_email)) {

                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_email);

                // Set parameters
                $param_email = trim($_POST["email"]);

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

                    /* store result */
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                        $error1 = '<font color="#dc3545"><b>'.$_POST["email"].'</b> is already in use</font>';
                    } else{
                        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
                    }
                } else{
                    $error1 = '<font color="#dc3545">Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later</font>';
                }
            }
        }

        // password validation
        if (empty(trim($_POST['password']))) {
            $error2 = '<font color="#dc3545">Your password is required</font>';
        } elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) < 6) {
            $error2 = '<font color="#dc3545">Password must be at leats 6 characters</font>';
        } elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) > 150) {
            $error2 = '<font color="#dc3545">Your password is to long</font>';
        } else {
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        }

        // check errors before inserting into database
        if (empty($error) && empty($error0) && empty($error1) && empty($error2)) {

            // prepare insert statement
            // user name, email, gender and password stored in table `users`
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, gender, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // user name, email and gender stored in table `users_profile`, username will be set as default user 'display_name'
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_profile(username, gender, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

            // user name stored in table `users_lastlogin_dt` to save user last login date
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_lastlogin_dt(username) VALUES(?)";

            // user name stored in table `users_lastlogin_ip` to save user last login ip address
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_lastlogin_ip(username) VALUES(?)";

            // user name, signup date and time stored in table `users_signup_dt` to save user signup date and time
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_signup_dt(username, date_n_time) VALUES(?, NOW())";

            // user name and signup ip address stored in table `users_signup_dt`
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_signup_ip(username, ip) VALUES(?, ?)";

            // user name stored in table `users_verified`
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_verified(username) VALUES(?)";

            // user name stored in table `users_mod_man_sec_ver_ser`
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users_mod_man_sec_ver_ser(username) VALUES(?)";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $insert)) {

                // bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_gender, $param_email, $param_password);

                // set parameters
                $param_username = $username; // user's name
                $param_gender = $gender; // user's gender
                $param_email = $email; // user's email
                $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // creates a password hash
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // grab users ip address

                // attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

                    $msg = '<div class="alert a_success alert-dismissable" id="alert"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a><b>Signup was successful</b></div>';
                } else {
                    $msg = '<div class="a_danger alert-dismissable" id="alert"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a><b>Signup was unsuccessful, please try again</b></div>';
                }
            }

            // close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        // close connection
        mysqli_close($db);
    }
    // echo success message or failed message
    echo $msg;
?>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                    <center><h3><b>Create a new account</b></h3></center><br>
                    <div class="form_box">
                        <form id="canabody" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-grou">
                                <b>Username</b>
                                <br>
                                <input class="form-control" id="uname" type="text" name="username" placeholder="3 - 15 characters" maxlength="15" value="<?php if(isset($username)) echo $username; ?>" autocomplete="off" required>
                                <?php echo $error; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <b>Gender</b>
                                <br>
                                <select class="form-control custom-select" name="gender" id="ugender" required>
                                    <option></option>
                                    <option value="male" <?php if(isset($gender) && $gender == 'male') echo 'selected'; ?>>Male</option>
                                    <option value="female" <?php if(isset($gender) && $gender == 'female') echo 'selected'; ?>>Female</option>
                                </select>
                                <?php echo $error0; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <b>Email address</b>
                                <br>
                                <input class="form-control"  id="usrem"  type="email" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo $email; ?>" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" required>
                                <?php echo $error1; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <b>Password</b>
                                <br>
                                <input class="form-control" id="usrpass" type="password" name="password" maxlength="150" value="<?php if(isset($password)) echo $password; ?>" placeholder="6 - 150 characters" required>
                                <?php echo $error2; ?>
                            </div>
                            <button id="ok_but0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="reg_submit">Create account</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I keep getting an error which says;

**Warning:** mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\d_project\signup.php on line 160

*"line 160:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_gender, $param_email, $param_password);".*

Comment: The second parameter to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` is a string where each character in the string represents the datatype of a to-be-bound parameter.  So "ss" means you will be binding two strings.  But you're passing 4 values to be bound.

Comment: You realize you keep overwriting `$insert`? You need to create the query string, bind params, execute, check for result, move to next.

Comment: i just changed the "ss" to "ssss" and am still having the same error @PatrickQ

Comment: but how? @ficuscr

Comment: I imagine that you're probably still getting _an_ error, but I doubt the _same_ error.

Comment: yes, your correct @PatrickQ

Comment: i just read the question you shared as a duplicate but my question is not yet answered, still getting the same error @PatrickQ

Comment: No, as you even just said, you are not getting the _same_ error.  The issue that you're having now is a result of the problem mentioned by ficuscr. Only one of your INSERT queries is actually being prepared. That would be the last one that you define, which only has one parameter in it. So the error that you're getting is due to attempting to bind four values to a query with only one parameter.

Comment: so how do i fix this? @PatrickQ

Comment: Read ficuscr's comment. You need to do some version of what you're doing now for _each_ of those INSERTs.

Comment: Oh my! I just tried to work something out, but the form data only inserts to a single column in my database. I think i can take it from here. Thank you for your help. :) @PatrickQ

Comment: Also, just FYI, most major systems I'm familiar with would be storing most of that data in _one_ table. That table would have individual _columns_ for `signupIp`, `signupTimestamp`, `lastLoginIp`, `lastLoginTimestamp`, etc

Comment: Thank you for adding more knowledge, your the best @PatrickQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem stuck on how the multiple inserts would work. I'll show an example of what Patrick Q and I are saying:

```
<?php

// set parameters
$param_username = $username; // user's name
$param_gender = $gender; // user's gender
$param_email = $email; // user's email
$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // creates a password hash
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // grab users ip address

//FIRST Insert
$insert = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, gender, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $insert);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $param_username, $param_gender, $param_email, $param_password);
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    ...
}

//SECOND Insert
$insert = "INSERT INTO users_signup_ip(username, ip) VALUES(?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $insert);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $ip);
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    ...
}
```

How you handle an error also gets more complicated. You could read up on transactions if you wanted one failure to abort all the inserts. Or you could just stop if an error is encountered. Or you could keep an array of errors and push to it and then list them all if the array is not empty.

It's not a trivial task for a beginner but this is a great exercise to learn from. As Patrick Q also observes a better understanding of what is required might make you reconsider the structure of the stored data.

Comment: Thank you, this has given me a proper understanding. Few data has successfully been inserted to my database. I think i can take it from here :)